# How do I convert or load a UIImage into a PKDrawing?

Tags: uikit, ipados, pencilkit

I'd like to be able to load a PNG file into a PKCanvasView to be able to draw on and erase parts of it. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: @TomKraina Not yet, trying to work around it.

Comment: Any update yet? I have the same problem. I'm gonna try dragging a `UIImageView` into the `PKCanvas`, as that seems to work

Comment: Any solution yet? I want to add u UIImage from the user into the canvas and do some editing with PencilKit

Answer (score 4):

First, put your UIImageView behind PKCanvasView, then set the PKCanvasView opaque to false, and color to clear.

Then in PKCanvasViewDelegate:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return YOUR_IMAGEVIEW
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offsetX: CGFloat = max((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0)
    let offsetY: CGFloat = max((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0)
    YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width * scrollView.zoomScale, height: self.view.bounds.height * scrollView.zoomScale)
    YOUR_IMAGEVIEW.center = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX, y: scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY)

}
```

As apple said, putting your imageView in viewForZooming is enough, but It doesn't work. So I added above codes in scrollViewDidZoom and it just works as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find any official documentation about this, but I make it work by adding a UIImageView as subview of first subview of PKCanvasView.
Zooming is also working perfectly by setting both .maximumZoomScale=1 and .minimumZoomScale=5

> But notice this might not work in the future as Apple might change their implementation of PKCanvasView

Here's the sample code for SwiftUI

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = PKCanvasView()
        ...
        ...
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.isOpaque = false
        view.maximumZoomScale = 5
        view.minimumZoomScale = 1

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "NameOfImage"))
        let contentView = Tool.getContentViewFromPkCanvasView(view)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        contentView.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
        return view
    }
```

```
class Tool{
    static func getContentViewFromPkCanvasView(_ view: UIView) -> some UIView {
        return view.subviews[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever, but unfortunately, it still just acts like a background image—you're not able to erase for example.

Comment: 1. this probably (i.e. most definitely) is a bad idea because apple can change the canvas view's internal structure at any time, in which case this would stop working (and would, in the worst case, crash); 2. there's no need to use `some UIView` as the return type. `subviews` is an `[UIView]`, so the type is fixed and the `some` doesn't do anything. (also, `UIView` is not generic in the first place)

Answer (score 3):

Use an UIImageView and put it behind PKCanvasView, then set the PKCanvasView opaque to false, and color to clear. Draw on it is fine, but erase is not possible.

Comment: But then the image doesn't move or scale with the PKCanvasView.

Comment: after how to save that image with drawingpls help

Answer (score 0):

Use setDrawing of PKCanvasView

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkcanvasview/3229950-drawing

See 26:53 duration of Session video 221

[image: See 26:53 of Session video 221]

Comment: This is for loading the drawings you saved, not for PNG.

Comment: maybe not useful for PNGs but I stumbled across this SO question and this answer is exactly what I needed. I'm making a drawing app and needed to figure out how to save and load drawings.